# HTML Email occasionally sending source code

Tags: php, html, email

At my company, we have had several clients claim that their order confirmation emails are coming through just as the HTML source, not formatted at all. However the majority of our clients are receiving their emails through fine.

I think I may have found a link which explains why only *some* clients receive the unformatted email, however I'm not sure of the cause. It seems that users with a custom domain name for their email address are experiencing the problems and regular email domains such as `@gmail.com` or `@icloud.com` are working fine.

The problem is ***not*** related to the client used to view the email as I have been able to replicate the problem with my private domain name and the source code is displayed in all clients.

Any idea what would be the cause of this?

Here are my headers:

```
$headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: ".$from."\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
```

Comment: Check your `Content-Type`.

Comment: @SLaks `Content-Type` is text/html

Comment: I've seen this type of question before, and it ended up as the OP's headers were not properly formatted.

Comment: check the content in the RECEIVED email, e.g. look at the email's raw source. something might have gotten lost/stripped while it was going through the various email systems.

Comment: also are you sending a plain-text part as well as the html part, or is it html only?

Comment: You should post your headers code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following headers for `HTML` Email...

```
$from = $from . ' <' . $from . '>';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Originating-IP: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem turned out to be two `Content-Type`s which has been set, and were conflicting with each other in some instances.