# Small amount of users receiving HTML email as source code

Tags: php, html, email

I've already asked this question before : [HTML Email occasionally sending source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609901/html-email-occasionally-sending-source-code)
But it seems that these solutions did not fix the problem.

We send HTML emails to our customers using PHP containing an order confirmation. The vast majority of customers receive these emails fine. 
However some users (people who have a private domain name) receive these emails as the source code. After making some tweaks to the headers, the problem now only occurs for a minority of users, and not for all users with a private domain name.

One of our customers sent us this, which is what he received as well as the email source code:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-MessageSniffer-Identifier: e:\SmarterMail\Spool\proc\work\1136252898525.eml
X-GBUdb-Analysis: 1, 162.13.103.84, Ugly c=0 p=0 Source New
X-MessageSniffer-Scan-Result: 0
X-MessageSniffer-Rules: 0-0-0-16102-c
X-RBL-Warning: BADROUTE: This E-mail was routed in a poor manner consistent with spam [2000010f].
X-RBL-Warning: ENVMISMATCH: Env sender (apache@513421-db1.comms-express.com) From: (websales@comms-express.com) mismatch.
X-Declude-Sender: apache@513421-db1.comms-express.com [162.13.103.84]
X-Declude-Spoolname: 1136252898525.eml
X-Declude-RefID: 
X-MessageStream-Note: Scanned by MessageStream (www.messagestream.com).
X-MessageStream-Scan: Score [4] at 13:23:17 on 01 May 2014
X-MessageStream-Tests: BADROUTE, ENVMISMATCH
X-Country-Chain: 'EU' [corrupt RIPE data]->UNITED KINGDOM->destination
```

I have never seen something like this so I don't even know where to begin. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction?

These are my headers:

```
$from = $from . ' ';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Originating-IP: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . "\r\n";
```

Comment: When you say 'source code', you meen `html` code?

Comment: certain mailboxes can read html while others seem to be unable to causing that problem. I resolved this to using \n instead of <br>. But it really depends on the mailserver from the recieving person

Comment: Some email client's doesn't interpret html. For example client's using POP protocol. You can create two mails : the first one in HTML at the beginning and the second one in plain text at the end of the mail. The one who can't read the HTML email could read the text email

Comment: @Gwenc37 There is no point in doing this as the user is still receiving the `html` source code, so they are still able to receive the email. But the fact that the email contains raw `html` causes the filter to kick up a fuss

Comment: I will say, @DanielJohnson, that this is a reason why I like using a mailing library instead of writing out headers from scratch. PHPmailer lets you have HTML and plaintext email bodies, which is _really_ handy for what you're apparently looking at.

Comment: @Gwenc37 The use of IMAP vs. POP has nothing to do with how email messages will be displayed.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Thanks a lot, I hadn't heard of that package before. I'll do some experimenting with it now!

Comment: Just to add, the recipient is using message stream which is a hosted exchange service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like those users have their e-mails turned into txt types of files, not HTML files to be interpreted.  The stuff you posted in the header is a normal e-mail header that is hidden from users who read the message, then stripped by the part that produces the message for the user.  I was once asked by a supervisor to authenticate the message, and that's essentially what it said.